# Find annulus of convergence for the following Laurent series

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

$ f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{-1} \dfrac{3^{{n}}z^n}{(-n)!} + \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{z^n}{3^n}$

I have no idea how to tackle this. Any ideas?

Comment: What is $n!$ if $n<0$ ?

Comment: In that first sum, $n!$ has to be a typo or you intend for something like $n! \equiv \Gamma(n+1)$. Please specify

Comment: Yes you are right, it was a typo.My bad! edited now

Comment: What do you know about the radius of convergence of the geometric and exponential series?

Comment: @LutzL nothing, honestly. My prof failed to explain it and everywhere online is extremely confusing. Any pointers would be lovely! :)

Comment: You should recognize that your expression is $\exp(\frac1{3z})-1+\text{geom}(\frac z3)$  and readily deduce the convergence region from that.

Comment: @LutzL how do you find convergence region from that? Sorry i genuinely have no idea

Comment: $\exp(u)$ converges for all $u$, $\text{geom}(v)$ converges for $|v|<1$. These should be known facts at this point in the lecture.